# mongodb add element in subset array give error

Tags: mongodb

I want to add an element in a subset array but it gives an error. How can I solve this problem?

error:

```
error: {
    "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: $push: { Questions: [ { _id: ObjectId('5565841ca6df1a168c4d8049'), CreationDate: new Date(1432716315502), IsActive: true, Name: \"uuu\", IsRequired: true, QuestionType: 1.0, AnswerInputType: 1.0, AnswerValidationPattern: null, AnswerValidationMessage: null, QuestionOrder: 0.0 } ] }",
    "code" : 17287
}
```

update query:

```
db.getCollection('forms').find({ "_id" : ObjectId("55657c94a6df1a155c779cd1") },

{
    "$push" : { 
        "Questions" : 
           [ {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5565841ca6df1a168c4d8049"), 
            "CreationDate" : ISODate("2015-05-27T08:45:16.502Z"), 
            "IsActive" : true,
            "Name" : "uuu", 
            "IsRequired" : true, 
            "QuestionType" : 1, 
            "AnswerInputType" : 1,
            "AnswerValidationPattern" : null,
            "AnswerValidationMessage" : null, 
            "QuestionOrder" : 0 
            } ]
    },
    "$inc" : { "QuestionCount" : 1 }  }

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replace the `find` method with `update`.
2. Use `$set` instead of `$push` to add the first element (or the whole Questions array if you may) and it will work ok.

You'll need push only to add new elements to the array after it's created, not while it's null. It should be something like this:

```
db.getCollection('forms').update(
    { "_id" : ObjectId("55657c94a6df1a155c779cd2") }, 
    { "$set" : { "Questions" : [
                       {"_id":ObjectId("55659c93a6df1a22e0f93a2b"),
                        "CreationDate": ISODate("2015-05-27T10:29:39.922Z"),
                        "IsActive" : true,
                        "Name" : "ddd",
                        "IsRequired" : false,
                        "QuestionType" : 1,
                        "AnswerInputType" : 1,
                        "AnswerValidationPattern" : null,
                        "AnswerValidationMessage" : null,
                        "QuestionOrder" : 0 
                       }]
    }, 
    "$inc" : { "QuestionCount" : 1 }
  })
```

Once this array is set to the value above, it will have one element. You can then push more elements to it using `push`:

```
db.getCollection('forms').update(
   {"_id": ObjectId("55657c94a6df1a155c779cd2")},
   {"$push": 
      {"Questions":
         {"_id": ObjectId("55659c93a6df1a22e0f93a2d"),
          "CreationDate" : ISODate("2015-05-27T10:40:39.922Z"),
          "IsActive" : true,
          "Name" : "ccc",
          "IsRequired" : false,
          "QuestionType" : 1,
          "AnswerInputType" : 1,
          "AnswerValidationPattern" : null,
          "AnswerValidationMessage" : null,
          "QuestionOrder" : 0 } },
   "$inc" : { "QuestionCount" : 1 } } )
```

Comment: ok but error changed. error :  The field 'Questions' must be an array but is of type NULL in document

Comment: I used your code to update a collection of my database. All I did was to replace the `find` with `update`. Did you check the matching of opening and closing brackets?

Comment: i check brackets but i dont find any things.again give error The field 'Questions' must be an array but is of type NULL in document {_id: ObjectId('55657c94a6df1a155c779cd1')}

Comment: db.getCollection('forms').update({ "_id" : ObjectId("55657c94a6df1a155c779cd1") },
{ 
    "$push" : { "Questions" : { "_id" : ObjectId("55659c93a6df1a22e0f93a2b"), "CreationDate" : ISODate("2015-05-27T10:29:39.922Z"), "IsActive" : true, "Name" : "ddd", "IsRequired" : false, "QuestionType" : 1, "AnswerInputType" : 1, "AnswerValidationPattern" : null, "AnswerValidationMessage" : null, "QuestionOrder" : 0 } }, 
    "$inc" : { "QuestionCount" : 1 } 
}
)

Comment: Could you pass the output of `db.getCollection('forms').find({ "_id" : ObjectId("55657c94a6df1a155c779cd1") })` here? I want to regenerate the element to get the exact element on my instance and test it.

Comment: /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55657c94a6df1a155c779cd1"),
    "CreationDate" : ISODate("2015-05-27T08:13:08.205Z"),
    "IsActive" : true,
    "Acls" : null,
    "QuestionCount" : 1,
    "Questions" : null,
    "Name" : "tes",
    "Description" : "te",
    "IsPublished" : false,
    "TemplatePath" : "2015\\5\\77ecdd15ba59446a8a7b89244d02a126",
    "StorageId" : ObjectId("55657c28a6df191c402e810a"),
    
}

Comment: "Questions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("55657c9da6df1a155c779cd2"),
            "CreationDate" : ISODate("2015-05-27T08:13:17.914Z"),
            "IsActive" : true,
            "Name" : "tr",
            "IsRequired" : false,
            "QuestionType" : 1,
            "AnswerInputType" : 1,
            "AnswerValidationPattern" : null,
            "AnswerValidationMessage" : null,
            "QuestionOrder" : 0
        }
    ]

Comment: I sent it in two parts because document size over max char. u find Questions in 2th part

Comment: I got your error. 
Your `Questions` array is null in the document. You can't use `$push` to add an element to a null value, since it's used to append a new element to a non-empty array. Null is not an array.
I'll update the answer with more details.

Comment: ok . i found it. thanks i change my C# class.crate empty array in constructor of my class

Comment: Excellent choice. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same error message with Ruby 2.7.1 and MongoID 7.1.2.

```
The field 'license_caches' must be an array but is of type null in document
```

I could solve it by checking if the embedded document is empty or not:

```
if self.license_caches.empty?
  self.license_caches = [licenseCach]
else 
  self.license_caches.push licenseCach
end
```

That did the trick for me. Hope that is helpful to everybody who gets the same error message.